# AWS Web ACL rule: alternatives to Referer

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, powershell, http-referer

I am looking for a way to limit access to AWS S3 hosted data in a controlled and at least semi-secure way. I have various resources in a number of S3 buckets, with CloudFront as CDN. I then have a WordPress based website using a theme that allows me to sell "courses". Finally I manage my domains so I can create a sub domain for the content download link, i.e. content.domainname.com.
Ideally I want to limit access to content to a specific set of courses, so only people who have bought the course, and are linking to the content from a web page in that course, can (easily) get at the data. 
I know I can use an AWS Web ACL rule to check the referer, to limit downloads to links on my domain. And I think I can expand on that to test more of the URL, so in ***www.domainname.com/paid***/coursename/page.html I could have a rule that tests for the bold portion of the path and refuses otherwise.
However, I also know that referer can be easily spoofed, and more importantly some browsers and internet security software will replace the referer, and I don't want my site security to force customers to change their security settings. So, is there another option, to include some sort of data in the HTTP request, that limits access in a way that is both somewhat secure, but not dependent on a client side settings? Perhaps something like a hash that I could include in the link itself? Or, maybe the WordPress API and AWS Web ACL Rules can communicate is some way so as to validate the logged on user has membership in the course? Grasping at straws here I suspect.

Additionally, there will be a PowerShell script that can be downloaded and run, which will access downloadable content as well. Again, I want to limit access, but in this case I need to be able to maintain the criteria on AWS as I have subscription and non subscription versions of the courses, and the PS script should only download for customers on subscription. So, I could provide the PS script with something like a customer ID, then maintain a list of customer IDs that are currently on subscription so the Web ACL rule could filter. But again, I suspect that HTTP header won't get the job done, because it could be changed by internet security at the customer location. But now I am limited by what PowerShell can do with regards to HTTP requests.

I know, rather an open ended question, but hopefully someone can at least point me in the right direction. It sure seems like both needs are something that AWS should be able to do, I am just so out of my depth here I don't know where to start, and AWS documentation requires that you have some clue to get you going.

Comment: WAF wouldn't help you in this, Do you have any option to configure cookies based authentication and further allow waf based on cookies and also verify cookies verification on backend ?

Comment: @ james-dean I looked into signed URLs and cookies, and that looks problematic. I am starting to think the solution may be to create a GUID for each customer, and a CName record that uses that GUID as the sub domain, then a CloudFront distribution for each customer, that is linked to that CName. Then I can provide the GUID to the customer, so the Powershell can build the path as defined in the CName record, and everything works. Customer stops paying subscription and I just disable the CName record and the Distribution, and my PowerShell provides an "error" explaining the issue. Thoughts?